# Is it possible to see all the variable and its value stored in browser momory?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

I would like to know the way to see all the variables and its saved values in google chrome using 'developer tool'. Can anybody help me..

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to navigate, but if you're using chrome:

F12 -> Elements -> (in the bottom right) Properites shows you all available nodes and their values.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you mean variables from your JavaScript file?

If yes, you can use debugger.

1. Open Dev Tools F12
2. Select Tab "Sources"
3. Find a .js file you want to debug
4. Put a breakpoint after a variable declaration
5. Refresh and you will see values of declared variables in scope.

More about this:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/?hl=en

https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-javascript-with-chrome-devtools-breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of output you're looking for?

```
for(var b in window) { 
  if(window.hasOwnProperty(b)) console.log(b); 
}
```

This will list everything available on the `window` object (all the functions and variables, e.g., `$` and `jQuery` on this page, etc.). Though, this is quite a list; not sure how helpful it is...

Otherwise just do `window` and start going down its tree:

```
window
```

This will give you `DOMWindow`, an expandable/explorable object.